# Logstash JDBC - how to process json field?

Tags: logstash, logstash-jdbc

I have postgresql which stores some data as json fields, eg:

```
{"adults":2,"children":{"total":0,"ages":[]}}
```

I'm using logstash-input-jdbc plugin to process the data
How do i parse json from jdbc? From logs i see that the fields arrive as PGObject:

```
"travelers_json" => #<Java::OrgPostgresqlUtil::PGobject:0x278826b2>
```

which has a `value` and `type` properties.

I've tried using json filter, but i don't know how to access the `value` property to feed to json filter? 
What i've tried:

```
 source => "[travelers_json][value]"
 source => "travelers_json.value"
 source => "%{travelers_json.value}"
```

I must be missing something very obvious here?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the simpliest way was to convert json  to text in postgresql:

```
SELECT travelers_json::TEXT from xxx
```

but i still would like to know how to access that PGobject